# Youtube does not work on any browser. Chrome, Mozilla, Edge, IE

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, microsoft-edge, mozilla

One day youtube stopped working on all browsers. It loads preview of the video and then loading infinite circle appears. Sometimes it shows the message: `if playback doesn't begin shortly, try restarting your device.` I cleared coockies, history etc. two times. I found something about the `hosts` file, but the original file contains the same exact thing the guide was recommending to replace. There similar problems with youtube, but i didn't find anything that could possibly solve the issue except the host file.

[image: chrome]

[image: mozilla]

[image: edge]

Comment: Can you send us the console output of the browsers? You can check the output by pressing F12 OR Fn + F12. A window will appear and search for "Console" that might be beside the "Inspector". If there are any errors or warnings, please specify

Answer (score 0):

Whether the problem only occurs on the YouTube site? Try to play some online video from another site, such as Bing and Google.

If this issue only occurs on the YouTube site, perhaps the issue is related the YouTube site, you could check the YouTube help [forum](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3037019?hl=en&ref_topic=9257580) and contact with them.

If another site also has the same problem, perhaps the issue is related to your network or computer. Please check the network connection and check which version of OS and Browser version are you using? Then, try to Restart your browser, Restart your router, Restart your computer or Update your browser to the latest version.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you use propper audio device.

[image]